# Mapbox Custom Marker but can't disable default marker

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I have made a lot of try and mix between the mapbox's examples and the stackflow's posts.
I can't disable the default blue marker but this code works fine.

```
    <link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.8.2/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.8.2/mapbox-gl.js"></script>

<style>
#map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:80%; }
#marker {
    background-image: url('https:/letraitdelas.ddns.net/test2/forecast/weather/113.png');
    background-size: cover;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.mapboxgl-popup {
    max-width: 200px;
}
</style>
<body>
<?php

$index = 0;
$towns = file_get_contents('towns.json');

$towns = json_decode($towns);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($towns);
echo "</pre>";

?>
<div id="map"></div>

<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'YOUR TOKEN HERE';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
    center: [2.751802, 47.50655],
    zoom: 10
});
<?php foreach($towns as $town){
$lat = $town[1];
$lon = $town[2];
?>

// var monument = [2.751802, 47.50655];
var town<?php echo $index; ?> = <?php echo "[" . $lon . ", " . $lat . "]"; ?>;

// create the popup
var popup<?php echo $index; ?> = new mapboxgl.Popup(
    {offset:[28, 0]}
).setText(
    'Location : Le Trait de Las'
);
// create the marker
let marker<?php echo $index; ?> = new mapboxgl.Marker().setLngLat(town<?php echo $index; ?>);

// get the marker element
const element<?php echo $index; ?> = marker<?php echo $index; ?>.getElement();
element<?php echo $index; ?>.id = 'marker<?php echo $index; ?>'
// hover event listener
element<?php echo $index; ?>.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => popup<?php echo $index; ?>.addTo(map));
element<?php echo $index; ?>.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => popup<?php echo $index; ?>.remove());

// add popup to marker
marker<?php echo $index; ?>.setPopup(popup<?php echo $index; ?>);
// add marker to map
marker<?php echo $index; ?>.addTo(map);

<?php 
$index = $index + 1;

}
?>
</script>

</body>
```

So my question is how to disable the blue marker and only have the marker that shows the weather (my variable custom icon) ?
The path of the weather icon is in the array 'towns.json' and is updated one time each day from a forecast weather api.

So in my loop I will change

```
background-image: url('https:/letraitdelas.ddns.net/test2/forecast/weather/113.png');
```

by the towns[3] value which is the path of the updated icon.
Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think i've solved it.

I took the examples of "popup hover" and "custom marker" on mapbox site.
I don't need the geoson array because I have a json which give me [latitude, longitude, location name, iconPath].

My code is only with one location but I just have to make my loops like I done in the first post.

I hope It can help someone else and I wait for all the comments and avices you can give to me.

Best Regards.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Add custom icons with Markers</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.8.2/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.8.2/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
<style>
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#map { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<style>
    .marker {
        display: block;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 50%;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 0;
    }
</style>

<div id="map"></div>

<script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'YOUR TOKEN HERE';

// Create a DOM element for each marker.
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
    center: [2.751802, 47.50655],
    zoom: 10
});

// Create a DOM element for each marker.
const el = document.createElement('div');
el.className = 'marker';
el.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://letraitdelas.ddns.net/test2/forecast/weather/113.png)';
el.style.width = '50px';
el.style.height = '50px';
el.style.backgroundSize = '100%';

// create the popup
var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup().setText('Location : Le Trait de Las');

// hover event listener
el.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => popup.addTo(map));
el.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => popup.remove());

let mymarker = new mapboxgl.Marker().setLngLat([2.751802, 47.50655]);

// add popup to marker
mymarker.setPopup(popup);

// Add markers to the map.
new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
    .setLngLat([2.751802, 47.50655])
    .addTo(map);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```